# Question text on the front page is mis-aligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

This morning (PST), everything looked normal. Now (2:45pm PST), across all sites I'm signed up to, on the right next to the votes on the left is blank space, with the question text beginning below it. This is on an iPhone 5s, newest iOS 9.2.1, mobile web version of SE (not app), Safari.

Clicking 'questions' once re-aligns everything properly, so not a big bug. The below is what I see after first going to any site.

[image]

Comment: Same behaviour in Chrome 48 on Android 4.2.2.

Comment: Same behaviour on chrome 48 over android 5.0.2.

Comment: The bug still appears on my handset (Apple 5 on latest iOS) - not in the home window, but when I click on a tag

Comment: In addition to tags, it's still broken on the Unanswered tab.

Comment: Can confirm Strawberry's and Emil's findings: Fixed on main pages, still exists on Unanswered & tag-specific pages

Comment: Yeap. I've updated my answer. Looks like it was fixed but not everywhere. Working on it right now.

Comment: This should be fixed now. Could someone else check as well so I can mark it as [status-completed]?

Comment: @Paweł' - Seems to be fixed for me now :)

Comment: @Robotnik done. :)

Comment: The corresponding MSO question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317533/height-vertical-size-of-question-summaries-now-too-large-on-mobile-site

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - This has been fixed.

Comment: I still have the issue. Could it just be some kind of time-delay?

Comment: @Strawberry Probably some time-delay / cache issue.

Comment: its fixed for me

Comment: As reported above, it's fixed on the main page, but broken on the unanswered tab and on listings for individual tags. It's also broken on a device I didn't use before the "fix". I thus find it *extremely* hard to believe this is due to caching.

Answer (score 7):

I also just raised this on [Arqade's Meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11326/28182):

It appears that the `.votes` CSS class is missing a `display: inline-block`, which is forcing the question title onto it's own line. Adding it back fixes the issue:

[image: Display: inline-block]